# Excel rank formula issue

Tags: excel

Formula

```
RANK(F2,$F$2:$F$5)
```

Output:

```
           
**sr  rank  name     sub1  sub2   sum      percentage**     
1     1     jaydeep  60    65     326      163
2     1     manish   70    63     326      163
3     3     jay 60   65    325.5  162.75
```

**Want:**

In rank column I get 3rd rank but actually it is 2nd rank.

Any way to get 2nd rank using formula because of sheet contain many data.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not comprehensible. Rephrase please.

Comment: No it's actually 3rd.

Comment: Okay Rephrase complete.

Comment: But it is possible to get it is 2nd @bernie.

Comment: Search for information about **Dense Rank**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want is called a **Dense Rank**

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY($F$2:$F$4,$F$2:$F$4) > 0) * (F2 <= $F$2:$F$5) )
```

Note that range within the `FREQUENCY` function is the same as the range to be ranked; and the range at the end has one additional row.

[image]