# How can I get a rank by category with ranks that are successive even with duplicate values?

Tags: excel, ranking, dense-rank

I have an array with employees that corresponds to different classes and that each have a score. I want to be able to rank these employees depending on their classes.

Right now I'm using `D2=(SUMPRODUCT((B2=$B$2,$B$9)*(C2<$C$2:$C$9))+1)`, which allows me to get the ranks, but when a score appears twice the ranks are not successive.

For example in the MWE below I get the ranks 1, 2 and 4 for class A and ranks 1 and 3 for class B, while I'd like just the ranks 1, 2 and 3.

[image: MWE]

*(the classes are sorted in this array for clarity but it won't be the case in my actual problem)*

Thanks for your help

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671093/excel-rank-formula-issue)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad : the use of Frequency is smart but I would need to be able to feed to it only the score cells corresponding to one category of the other and I do not know how to to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the FREQUENCY version:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$9=B2,$C$2:$C$9),$C$2:$C$9)>0)*($C$2:$C$10>=C2))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Note that the range on the end is one more row than the others.

[image: My]

---

If one has access to the New Dynamic Array formula then this gets ***A LOT*** easier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$9,$B$2:$B$9=B2))>=C2))
```

[image]

Comment: Well done! I'm not there yet though: I copied your answer but instead of getting "2 3 2 1 1 2 1 2" in column I I get "2 3 2 1 2 4 2 4", do you know why could that be?

Comment: No idea, is your data exactly like the pictures?

Comment: @LoBo My Bad, My version no longer requires the Array entry and I forget to tell people to do so.  You will need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.